# How to insert a name of the file as a header of a file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, filenames

Example: File name: ENSG00000000003

```
ENSG00000000003 43120.829491094
ENSG00000000005 39604.4956791524
ENSG00000000419 7645.05624570546
ENSG00000000457 2157.49855156382
ENSG00000000460 3317.98417717746
ENSG00000000938 6327.40515535397
```

Expected output; ideally, the filename is preceded by a tab:

```
    ENSG00000000003
ENSG00000000003 43120.829491094
ENSG00000000005 39604.4956791524
ENSG00000000419 7645.05624570546
ENSG00000000457 2157.49855156382
ENSG00000000460 3317.98417717746
ENSG00000000938 6327.40515535397
```

I want to do this in loop for my 45000 files together

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use the standard UNIX editor ([of course!](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html)):

```
for f in ENSG*
do
  printf '1i\n\t%s\n.\nw\nq\n' "$f" | ed -s "$f"
done
```

This sends a small script of commands to `ed`, namely:

- at line 1, insert (`i`) some text; the text is passed through `printf` as the filename, preceded by a tab (`\t`)
- after inserting that text (`.`), save the file to disk (`w`) and quit (`q`)

If, indeed, the number of files exceeds the command-line limit, then you could use a `find` command; adjust the parameters (starting directories, filenames, etc) as needed:

```
find . -name 'ENSG*' -exec sh -c 'printf "1i\n\t%s\\n.\nw\nq\n" "$1" | ed -s "$1" ' findsh {} \;
```

The core solution is the same, but wrapped in what I call a "find shell" -- `find` executes `sh -c ...` for each (single) filename that matches; the `findsh` string is a stub name for `$0` and the filename is passed to that shell in place of the `{}` curly braces. The shell itself then has the filename as parameter `$1`, so that's what the `printf` and `ed` commands use.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, still using `ed`, with `zsh`, a single invocation and no command-line limit (length or number of arguments):

```
printf 'e %s\n1i\n\t%1$s\n.\nw\nq\n' * | ed
```

(`zsh`’s `printf` supports `%m$` specifiers to re-use arguments.)